# Concatenation string variables from an array gives unexpected quotes in Perl

Tags: arrays, string, perl, concatenation

I have a CSV file that I need to enclose each value in quotes, where each value is a string. I'm getting unexpected quotes when concatenating

```
$outline = "";
$line = "John,Smith,jsmith@bogusaddress.net,000-0000";
@parts = split (',',$line);
for $part (@parts) {
    $part = '"' . $part . '"';
    if ($outline eq "") {
        $outline = $part;                  # reconstruct line
    } else {
        $outline = $outline . "," . $part;
    }
}
$outline = $outline . "," . '"' . $parts[0] . " " . $parts[1] . '"';
print "$outline\n";
```

I expected:

```
"John","Smith","jsmith.net","000-0000","John Smith"
```

but I got:

```
"John","Smith","jsmith.net","000-0000",""John" "Smith""
```

Why am I getting the extra quotes?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you on a late version of 5? 5.16 or 5.18?

Comment: This is not your actual code, because if it were, `@bogusaddress` would have been interpolated as an array.

Comment: I am using 5.16.3

My apologies. I had real data in a file. I took one line and used it for this question. At the last minute I decided to make it fake data. I got interrupted while doing so. The line in the file read in does have @ in the email addresses (with no escaping) and it is handled fine (not interpreted as an array).

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I probably should have explained I am an electronics designer. Learned Fortran IV in the 70's. Have only had basic intro to Perl. Hence the overly complicated and verbose code. I don't know the elegant ways discussed in many solutions. Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: @TLP, the "array" was interpolated away. The OP obviously didn't turn on warnings. That's why he got 'jsmith.net'.

Comment: @Axeman Oh, good catch, I didn't even see that part. I guess I just assumed he would have mentioned something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$part` in the `foreach` loop *aliases* each element of `@parts`. So you're actually storing back into the array, the strings you wrapped with quotes.

Try using [**`Data::Dumper`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDumper) and dump `@parts` at the bottom of each loop.

```
use Data::Dumper;

...
print Dumper( \@parts );
```

Answer (score 6):

A lot of practical solutions have been provided, I however wanted to address your question: *Why does this happen?*

The reason you are getting the double double quotes is that you are actually changing the elements of `@parts`. Inside a `for` loop, the elements are aliased to the loop arguments, so any changes to them directly are made on the "real" values as well. Consider the following:

```
my @foos = 1 .. 3;
for my $foo (@foos) {
    $foo += 1;
}
print "@foos";  # prints 2 3 4
```

So when you change `$part` in your code, the array `@parts` is also changed, and becomes like this (`Data::Dumper` output):

```
$VAR1 = [
          '"John"',
          '"Smith"',
          '"jsmith@bogusaddress.net"',
          '"000-0000"'
        ];
```

And from that point on, you cannot put together the string `"John"` and `"Smith"` without first removing the quotes again.

I also prepared a solution using `Text::CSV`, and I see [ThisSuitIsBlackNot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot) has already done so, so you can take a look at [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22511267/725418) for a practical solution.

For a more lightweight solution you can use `Text::ParseWords`. This, like `Text::CSV`, has the benefit of handling quoted delimiters.

```
use Text::ParseWords;

my $line = 'John,Smith,jsmith@bogusaddress.net,000-0000';
my @parts = quotewords(",", 0, $line);
push @parts, "@parts[0,1]";
print join ",", map qq("$_"), @parts;
```

Answer (score 2):

I always use [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV) when working with delimited data. It allows you to easily change delimiters, quoting behavior, and escape characters, and handles fields that contain the delimiter, which is difficult to handle on your own (although this isn't applicable to your example).

The following will quote all of the fields in the file `input.csv` and write the results to `STDOUT`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    binary => 1,
    auto_diag => 1,
    always_quote => 1,
    eol => $/
}) or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag;

open my $fh, '<', 'input.csv' or die "input.csv: $!";

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    $csv->print(\*STDOUT, $row);
}

close $fh;
```

*input.csv*

```
John,Smith,jsmith@bogusaddress.net,000-0000
Jane,Doe,jdoe@bogusaddress.net,000-0000
```

*Output*

```
"John","Smith","jsmith@bogusaddress.net","000-0000"
"Jane","Doe","jdoe@bogusaddress.net","000-0000"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use a `for` loop to string together the various parts. If you can use `split`, you can use `join`:

```
my $line = "John,Smith,jsmith@bogusaddress.net,000-0000";
my @parts = split  /,/, $line;             # Split the line on commas
my $new_line = join q(","), @parts;        # Separate out the parts with quote-comma-quote
my $new_line = qq("$new_line");            # Add pre and post quotes
```

The `q(...)` is a [quote-like](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) operator that acts as a single quote. The `qq(...)` is a *quote-like* operator that acts as double quotes. It's a bit easier to understand `qq("$line")` and `q(",")` instead of `"\"$line"\"` or `'","'`.

I'm using join to join all the parts with `","`. That handles the separation in the middle of `$new_line`, but doesn't handle the beginning and ending quote. Thus, I need a second command line to add the pre and post quotes.